# insert an template object in vector with inheritance c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the class `Deposito` defined with a template and I want to create a object of `Depositos_Normais` but it gives me this error message:

```
 error: cannot convert Depositos_Normais<Depositos<int>*>* to 
 Depositos<Depositos>>* in assignment
```

`Depositos` class:

```
template <class T>
class Depositos {
public:
  Depositos(int id, int num_palets, int capac_max, int area_total); 
}
template <class T>
Depositos<T>::Depositos(int id, int num_palets, int capac_max, int area_total) {...}
```

Depositos_normais class:

```
template <class T>
class Depositos_Normais : public Depositos<T> {
public:
  Depositos_Normais(int id, int num_palets, int capac_max, int area_total):
}
template <class T>
Depositos_Normais<T>::Depositos_Normais(
  int id, int num_palets, int capac_max, int area_total
):
  Depositos<T>(id, num_palets, capac_max, area_total)
{
```

Main.cpp:

```
Armazem<Depositos<int>> arm (1,1,1,1);
Depositos <int>* d= new Depositos_Normais<int>(int,int,int,int)
vector<Depositos<T>*> dep;
dep.push_back(&d);
```

anyone knows want's wrong??

```
EDIT::
template <class T>
void Armazem<T>::criarDepositoNormal(Depositos<T> &Dep) {
depos.push_back(Dep);
   }

main.cpp
Depositos <int>* d= new Depositos_Normais<int>(int,int,int,int);
arm.criarDepositoNormal(d);   <-Error  no know conversion for argument 1 from 'Depositos<int>*' to 'Depositos<Depositos<int>>&'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong line:

```
Depositos <T>* d= new Depositos_Normais<T>(int,int,int,int)
```

simply reading it you have no specified a type to use for the instantiation/template definition.
The code is provided is too poor but you have to substitute 'T' with a valid type.
Like

```
Depositos <float>* d= new Depositos_Normais<float>(int,int,int,int)
```

Comment: You cannot use T in your main.cpp when you are declaring the vector, use <int> instead.

Comment: i update the code but give me this error message: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<Depositos<int>>::push_back(Depositos<int>**)' :/

Comment: @user3689180 `d` is already a pointer, you just need `dep.push_back(d);`. `&d` creates a pointer-to-pointer (`Despositos<int>**`).

Comment: last question, i have this method createDN(const Depositos<T> &d){    dep.push_back(d);  }  but gives me the same error. i send Depositos<int>*d= new Deposito_Normais<int>(1,1,1,1);    if i change & to * will work?

Comment: In your method, as d is a reference, use &d in order to have a pointer: push_back(&d)